# Git: made commits to my master branch i opened pull request and now can't implement new features

Tags: git, github

I forked popular project on GitHub that i want to contribute to.

Now i made some changes to my master branch and pushed them to my master branch and made a pull request.

However my pull request is now being reviewed so i wanted to work on new feature until it gets merged.

I create new branch, add those new features and than i once again made pull request, but now the features i implemented in the master branch are also in my new branch so my second pull request has more features than i want to push to the original project.

The question is how can i now reset a branch to the original situation of the project, so that every new commit is just a build on the original project(without my patches on master).

Basically i screwed instead of starting with newFeature branch i commited and pull requested on my master, so now every branch(which of course is based of master) has features that are not in the original project + the new features that branch is made for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `upstream` is the name of the original repository on github (not your fork)

```
# Just to ensure to get the most actual commits too
git fetch --all
git checkout -b feature/newFeature upstream/master
```